# Why do I get a type error when I attempt to update the value attribute of Progressbar in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, typeerror

I am using Python 3.8.2
I have the following code that has 3 main loops. I need a simple UI that shows the progress for each loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import json
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.filename = ''
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Upload File', command = self.get_file).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Verify', command = self.verify).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        # tk.Label(self, text = 'some name').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.mainloop()

    def get_file(self):
        self.filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select File", filetypes = [("JSON", "*.json")])
        tk.Label(self, text = self.filename).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    def verify(self):
        tk.Label(self, text = 'Verifying Trustee Public Keys').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        ttk.Progressbar(self,
                   length = 100,
                   orient = "horizontal",
                   maximum = len(self.data["trustee_public_keys"]),
                   value = 0).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        i = 1
        for trustee_key_list in self.data['trustee_public_keys']:
            print('Trustee :', i)
            //some code
            i = i+1
            ttk.Progressbar['value'] =  i
```

Everytime I run it I get the error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Student User/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch_17.py", line 81, in verify
ttk.Progressbar['value'] =  i
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the intended result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to assign a value to the progressbar type while you should assign the value to the instance of the progressbar.

```
def verify(self):
        tk.Label(self, text = 'Verifying Trustee Public Keys').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        progress = ttk.Progressbar(self,
                   length = 100,
                   orient = "horizontal",
                   maximum = len(self.data["trustee_public_keys"]),
                   value = 0)
        progress.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        i = 1
        for trustee_key_list in self.data['trustee_public_keys']:
            print('Trustee :', i)
            //some code
            i = i+1
            progress['value'] =  i
```